# Accessibility error - Empty link. A link contains no text. - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, colors, accessibility

As you can check in the following link

https://benetialingerie.gr/product-category/%ce%ac%ce%bd%ce%b4%cf%81%ce%b5%cf%82/

there are some color attributes.

In the following link, you can check a report via webaim with some accessibility errors.

https://wave.webaim.org/report#/https://benetialingerie.gr/product-category/men/?lang=en

Just because all colors are buttons too, I want to insert somewhere an alt txt or something which, if I understand right, points out that it is a link.
The error I got is:

```
Empty link
A link contains no text.
```

Due to my limited developing skills, I don't know where exactly I must edit the code. I found something relevant, a plugin called "Variation Swatches for WooCommerce".

Can anyone help me out fixing this?

Comment: The color buttons are rendered via html anchor tab (<a></a>). Technically, this tag requires to have some human readable text like, <a>Click here</a>. Since these color buttons don't have any text hence the error. If these color buttons are created via any plugin, I am afraid you may not be able to edit those.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) to your link.  It will not only make the WebAIM/WAVE report happy, it will also allow a screen reader to hear the color name when they navigate to the link.

```
<a aria-label="red" href="https://benetialingerie.gr/product-category/%ce%ac%ce%bd%ce%b4%cf%81%ce%b5%cf%82/?filter_color=%ce%ba%cf%8c%ce%ba%ce%ba%ce%b9%ce%bd%ce%bf" rel="nofollow" class="rtwpvs-term-span rtwpvs-term-span-color" style="background-color:#db100a;" role="link"></a>
```

Note that you have `role="link"` on the `<a>`. The [default role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-a) of an `<a>` element is already a link so the `role` attribute is not needed.